# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

Dependency injection woes - I double checked my factory method edition.

I have a class:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
private readonly string _version;

  public MyService(string version)
  {
    _version = version;
  }
}
```

I have another class:

```
public class VersionedAssembly : IVersionedAssembly
    {
        public string Version { get; } = typeof(VersionedAssembly).Assembly.GetName().Version!.ToString();
    }
```

I register my services like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IVersionedAssembly, VersionedAssembly>();
services.AddScoped<IMyService>(provider =>
    {
        string version = provider.GetRequiredService<IVersionedAssembly>().Version;
        return new MyService(version);
    })
```

I attempt to run my code, and I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyService'.'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) in /_/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/CallSiteFactory.cs:line 518
```

I've tried paring down the registration to just

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService>(provider => new MyService("1"));
```

but this produced no change in error message. I'm super confused about what's going on, because all the results I can find for people asking about "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String'", the answer has been "you need to provide a factory method", and I have done. I tried putting a breakpoint against `string version = provider.GetRequiredService<IVersionedAssembly>()` but it didn't get hit. Any ideas?

Comment: your code works perfectly fine on a new project. Is it possible that you registered `MyService` twice in your project and now just face the ambiguity problem?